# Select-String for parsing a Cisco config file

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to parse a show tech config file from a cisco router.

The config file is huge so I need to capture everything in between two strings... For Example:

```text
------------------ show running-config ------------------

everything here

------------------ show redundancy history ------------------
```

I've been able to do it via REGEX:

```sh
$TechFile = "filepath"

$Cisco = Get-Content $TechFile

$ShowRunningCfgPattern = "------------------ show running-config ------------------(.*?)------------------ show redundancy history ------------------"

$Results = [regex]::Match($Cisco,$ShowRunningCfgPattern).Groups[1].Value
```

However this is not an ideal solution as it just clusters everything together making it parsing this information any further impossible

Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read section of lines from Cisco IOS configuration loaded as text file in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654464/read-section-of-lines-from-cisco-ios-configuration-loaded-as-text-file-in-powers)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the linenumber/index of the particular strings first, then use select-object to only select the lines within those ranges.
See below code example of this, tested on my machine with success:

```
$startSTR = "------------------ show running-config ------------------"
$endSTR = "------------------ show redundancy history ------------------"

$testfile = "C:\Temp\test.txt"

$content = get-content $testfile
$startIndex = $content.indexof($startSTR) + 1
$endIndex = $content.indexof($endSTR) -1
$desiredContent = $content | select-object -index ($startIndex..$endIndex)
$desiredContent
```

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon you are probably right. Unfortunately i've been unable to do something like  the below due to the need to have the index defined first `get-content | select-object -index (($_ | select-string $startSTR).LineNumber...(($_ | select-string $endSTR).LineNumber-2)) `

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon This seems terribly obvious now that you have stated it. Updated sample script to reflect this, only reading the file once

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I was looking to do.